# "I'll let you know" variations

Tags: phrase-usage, phrase-choice

What other possible ways of saying "I'll let you know"? I heard people in Northern Ireland say" I'll give you a shout", but I'm not sure it has the same meaning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The phrase

> **I'll let you know**

us usually used to tell someone they'll keep you **updated** on a decision or situation.
Other phrases that can be used are

> **I'll tell you as soon as I know
>
>   I'll keep you updated
>
>   I'll keep you posted**

Your second phrase

> **I'll give you a shout**

usually only means someone will contact you regardless of the situation and may or may not have the same meaning as "I'll let you know", it would depend on context and custom.

> I'll **give you a shout** and **let you know** when I find out.
>   I'll **give you a shout** to arrange meeting up later this week.